# Looping insert statement in SQL without using cursor

Tags: sql, loops, insert

I have a problem with looping in SQL.
I want to loop a startdate until he reaches the enddate.

They said to me not to use a cursor, so I found an example like this:

```
with mycte as
(
select cast('2007-01-01' as datetime) DateValue
union all
select DateValue + 1
from mycte 
where DateValue + 1 < '2030-12-31'
)
select * from mcte
```

This works, so I changed the variables to my situation:

```
with View_Solidnet_Training as
(
select StartingDate as DateValue
union all
insert into OBJ_Availability values(34, DateValue + 1, 'AM', 2, 'Test')
select DateValue + 1
from View_Solidnet_Training
where DateValue + 1 < EndingDate
)
select * from View_Solidnet_Training
```

But I get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'insert'. Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 The name "DateValue" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Incorrect syntax near ')

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'insert'.                                       
Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
The name "DateValue" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.                               
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Please don't post vital information as comments. Edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
with View_Solidnet_Training as
(
    select @StartingDate as DateValue

    union all

    select DateValue + 1
    from View_Solidnet_Training
    where DateValue + 1 < @EndingDate
)
insert into OBJ_Availability
select 34, DateValue + 1, 'AM', 2, 'Test' from View_Solidnet_Training
```

Provided `@StartingDate` and `@EndingDate` are two date time variables adn table `OBJ_Availability` should contain only 5 columns in the selected order of CTE.

Comment: Seems nice, but error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: `StartingDate` should be a variable like `@StartingDate` and set a minimum date value for that.

Comment: Can't answer my own question. 
link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896138/looping-sql-statement-insert

Comment: Thanks!! The only fault was that an insert statement don't need the  values-word! Thanks Techdo!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
with mycte as
(
  select 34, cast('2007-01-01' as datetime) DateValue, 'AM', 2, 'Test' 
  union all
  select 34, DateValue + 1, 'AM', 2, 'Test'
    from mycte 
   where DateValue + 1 < '2030-12-31'
)
insert into OBJ_Availability (select * from mcte)
```